# How do I assign a cell formula containing symbols using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m using VBA and I have to insert this formula `=SE($w2="s"; SE($C2-(+Foglio1!$F2))>0;"▲";"▼"; "";)`
 on the cell in excel’s file, and then run the **Macro**.

How do I write these symbols ▲ ▼ in the macro such that they show up in the cell's formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters ▲ and ▼ are respectively  known as [Black up-pointing triangle](http://unicode-table.com/en/25B2/), and [Black down-pointing triangle](http://unicode-table.com/en/25BC/) in Unicode. Their respective code are `U+25B2` and `U+25BC`.

So if you want to use them inside a macro, you need to use the `ChrW` function like this:

```
[A1].Formula = "=SE($w2=”s”; SE($C2-(+Foglio1!$F2))>0;""" & ChrW(&H25B2) & """;""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """; """";)"
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry but i started to use vba just a few days ago, could you tell me in which way i have to write the code in macro's txt?
 for example:
Sub marine(I)
With Range("A1")
    .Value = "HelloWord"
    .Value = Mid(.Value, 1, I) & ChrW(9786) & Mid(.Value, I + 1, 9999)
    .Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS"
End With
End Sub

Comment: @user3619429 I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve here. You want to set "HelloWorld" to A1 and then change A1 with a formula? Please edit your question with your code and explanation and I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you to be so patience, at this moment this is the situation: Range("F5").Select ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ [F5].Formula = "=IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[17]=""s"", IF (Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[16]-Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[15]>0;""" & ChrW(&u25B2) & """;""" & ChrW(&u25BC) & """;) """";)" when the macro runs the editor find a syntax problem, why? what is the problem? i tried to fix by myself but i didn't solve it and doesn't compare black up point triangle.
Thank you!!!!

Comment: @user3619429 You can't assign twice in the same line. Either write `Range("F5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[17]=""s"", IF (Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[16]-Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[15]>0;""" & ChrW(&H25B2) & """;""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """;) """";)"` or `Range("F5").Select` followed by `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[17]=""s"", IF (Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[16]-Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[15]>0;""" & ChrW(&H25B2) & """;""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """;) """";)"`. Note that `Range("F5")` is equivalent to `[F5]`

Comment: I've insert: Range("F5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[17]=""s"", IF (Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[16]-Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[15]>0;""" & ChrW(&H25B2) & """;""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """;) """";)"
but the editor continous to find error in this line, probably i hade mastakes because i'm not expert.
could i send to you an email with the txt so you can check my mastakes????
thank you in advance, anyway you were great!

Comment: @user3619429 remove space after IF, replace `;` with `,`, add missing `,` and this should work: `Range("F5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[17]=""s"",IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[16]-Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[15]>0,""" & ChrW(&H25B2) & """,""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """), """")"`

Comment: Could you advice to me another way to insert the  Black up-pointing triangle in VBA because the previous comment doesn't run, the macro find error precisely in that line.... thank you in advance.... it's a work staff otherwise i'm not going to ask to you once again... thank you

Comment: @user3619429 I just tried it, and for some reason when I copy paste my previous comment in the VBA editor, an extra `?` is added where the line breaks. I suggest you check for that, if I remove it this works correctly

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuu it workkkkkkksssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! you're a genius!!!!!!

Comment: if i want to give red or green color depending if there a decreasing  or increasing level?

Comment: @user3619429 I'm sure this question has already been answered here, if not feel free to ask a new one

Comment: sorry i tries to post a new question but nobody answer to me, it's a work staff and if it is no urgent i will not ask you again... but please could you help me? Thank you!